# cakephp, Facebook Connect webtechnick plugin

Tags: facebook, cakephp, plugins

I'm using the webtechnick Facebook plugin to use Facebook authentication in my cakephp application.
It was working fine till yesterday. Now whenever I try to login using Facebook details, the login button will change to logout but I can get the Facebook id or other information.

What is the problem?

---

EDIT

I am using

```
if($this->Connect->user()){
    .............
    .............
}
```

function in app_controller.php `$this->Connect->user()` function will give the logged in users's information, if the user's Facebook username/password is correct.

I'm getting an empty result for this function.

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Facebook->logout();    
?>
```

The above code will give me a Facebook login button, when the user is not logged in to Facebook, after a successful login using Facebook credentials this button will change into Facebook logout.

Now I am getting this Facebook login button changed into logout, but no Facebook details.

Comment: Without any code it's not possible to answer your question. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it,

it is because difference between the site url and url that I use to register in the facebook API.

In facebook I use www.  prefix for registering my app, but sometimes I use to access the site without 'www.' prefix. This makes the problem.